# Start activity on boot

Tags: android, android-manifest, boot

I'd like to start my app just after the phone boot. Apparently the app is started after the boot but it immediately crashes (just to be clear the app normally works fine). I have already read and tried different solutions ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853879/start-an-activity-on-phone-boot-in-android), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476335/application-is-not-starting-on-device-boot)) and actually the same code works fine with another app I was developing. Here's the code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothx10y"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="6"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter">
            </meta-data>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" />        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver.java:

```
    public class StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {    

                Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);

            }    
    }   
}
```

Could it be related the fact that I'm using the a lot of user permissions?

Comment: What is your problem description exactly?

Comment: The app simply crashes after the boot...just to be clear the app normally works fine.

Comment: do you have the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Inside the OnCreate() I had this code (related to the USB communication) which was causing the crash:

```
    act_string = getIntent().getAction();
    if( -1 != act_string.indexOf("android.intent.action.MAIN")){
        restorePreference();
    }           
    else if( -1 != act_string.indexOf("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED")){
        cleanPreference();
    }
```

Deleting this code solved the start after boot issue.

Answer (score 22):

```
Try this:
```

> 1] In AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <application 
 ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </application>
```

> 2] Inside BroadcastReciever class with StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver as class name.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i); 

}
```

This worked for me. The difference in code is as follows:

- android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" inside receiver.
- included "category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" " inside intent filter.
- **I am not checking the intent in onRecieve, as i know that code will be executed only if its true**

Comment: I tried your code but in that way the app is not even started after the boot (so it does not crash)

Comment: Without i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) I couldn't start my activity. So that seems to be mandatory in this case. This answer is very good.

Answer (score 6):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>    
<receiver android:name=".StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver"
                      android:enabled="true"
                      android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Answer (score 3):

do it like this in if condition

```
 if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
```

Answer (score 1):

in place of

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

add also this

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

some devices like HTC don't catch `BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: The thing is that the same code I posted in my question works fine on the same device but with another app. Anyway I tried to add the line, same problem

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the whole manifest file which workedv for me on oppo neo 5.
And,even take care that some phone requires special access to achieve boot start or other special permissions.So,don't forgot to allow the accesses to your app!!.

Here's the code -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="SilversithService"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.AndroidServiceStartOnBoot"
            android:enabled="true"></service>
        <activity
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="SilversithService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <receiver
        android:name="tv.usa.rytek.services.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferenceHelper sharedPreferenceHelper;
private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    sharedPreferenceHelper = new SharedPreferenceHelper(context);
    Log.e(TAG,""+intent.getAction());
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        if(sharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferenceAutoPosition()==1){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

}