# BroadCastReceiver Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm realy newbie in android, and i'm having dificult with broadcastreceiver in my project.

I've created uses-permission and the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml, created the class but it not passing on the logcat message.

**MY RECEIVER CLASS**

```
package com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Script", "Passou AQUI");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, VerificaNovoFreteService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

**MY ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

What i'm doing wrong? Please, help me!

Comment: Have you registreted it as the reciever?

Comment: You need to use this receiver somewhere in your activity; So that when something happens, it does something onReceive

Comment: @Felipe A. use GCM server?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611048/start-activity-on-boot/17611216#17611216

Comment: BroadCastReceiver run only once time when i'm using on BOOT_COMPLETED or it run until remove the application?

Comment: Do you have any activities in your application? Have you started the application at least once after installing it on your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every Phone sends the `BOOT_COMPLETED` Broadcast. For example, I think it was HTC, sends the  `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` Broadcast, if it has boot up. Also your logcat is maybe not connected to your phone at Boot-Up-Time. I'd suggest to create a `Toast` to check, wether your `Boot-Reciever` is executed.

You can create this `Toast` with this code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boot-Reciever Started", Toast.LENGT_LONG);
```

Comment: I'm using a Nexus S, do you thing it can run the BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: Probably it will run the BOOT_COMPLETED.

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe A., it's possible that you have a problems with CPU...The oficial documentation talks about it, and says the best use is WakefulBroadcastReceiver guarantee a that CPU will stays awake, you can read this post that talk about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26380942/3996257

This is my code with WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntent_Service.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

The gcm receiver needs to add your package in your intent-filter it's the only difference with my code. And my receiver have this code:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".App_Services.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />/>
            <category android:name="your.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It's possible your code don't recognizes your receiver because  doesn't know their package. Tell me if I helps you, good luck!