# Push Notifications not received when the App is force-stopped

Tags: android

The Push Notifications are received fine when the App is closed by navigating back or when closed from Recent Apps.

But when the App is force-stopped from Settings, then the App doesn't receive the Push Notifications. I don't know if it is a limitation of the platform or I'm missing something.

How to change the App to receive Push Notification even if force-stopped?

Comment: what's your real question?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai edited the question

Comment: of course it will not receive the notifications. if you force close an app, also its broadcastreceiver gets shut down. if you dont restart the receiver automatically, it will not receive anything

Answer (score 1):

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105498/3996257) please! It's possible that you uses a simple broadcast receiver then broadcast receiver don't guarantee the service is working always finally if you want to have service works all time you need to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver class.

---

-- Edited 2 hours later --

This is not limitation from WakefulBroadcastReceiver class, then you're missing something because WakefulBroadcastReceiver class it's prepared for this situations. If I force to close my app this one can receive notifications from the GCM in my case... Then I have a few questions...

- It's obviously that something is incorrect... We need to see your code (Receiver and Intent).
- In the other cases you can receive push?

---

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Comment: I use WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: Yes and when come a new push he capture it!! It's  WakefulBroadcastReceiver he's never die! The special from WakefulBroadcastReceiverm it's the cpu never can kill this process, you can try to kill from notification bar or from settings that when comes a new push WakefulBroadcastReceiver is activated to capture this!