# Activity don't starts at boot completed

Tags: android

I have `Activity`

```
public class I1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    }

}
```

and `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class I2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, I1.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);
    }

}
```

Why don't my activity starts at boot completed? That's code of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.6" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name=".I1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".I2"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and code of layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.mypackage.Main" />
```

Can you help me please, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please specify device name with OS.

Comment: The intent is received ? Is there any exception ? And last one, is the app on a SD card ?

Comment: No any exception logged. I using USB debugging logcat. I tried to install app on phone and on SD card too. Intent was not received. Phone - Philips Android 4.0.3.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/4467208). It's not an Activity, but it may be the same reasoning.

Comment: @MuratK., I have already read this answers, they didn't helped solve the problem. And I also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611048/start-activity-on-boot answer.

Comment: You might want to use the fully qualified name instead of this `android:name=".I1"`

Comment: @MuratK., ok i try to try.

Comment: @AxelH, I use ADB. I added `Log.v("", "Receiver");` in `onReceive(...)` method. It was not logged. I was waiting 2-3 minutes after i turned phone on.

Comment: @MuratK., I tried. Nothing changed and activity didn't started.

Comment: @AxelH, java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @AxelH, I tried -n instead of -p. `Error: Bad component name: com.mypackage`

Comment: @AxelH, just now did it!) Doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127361/discussion-between-axelh-and-lesperanza).

Comment: @AxelH, I understand what was the problem with the second Philips. I wrote you in chat.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was really unbeliveable. I have two identical phones - Philips Android 4.0.3. One of them, on which I tested my app had bug with `BOOT_COMPLETED` action.
This code is the best I think

```
<receiver
    android:name=".I2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and Broadcast Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, I1.class);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

and it also works!

Thanks to user @AxelH!

---

**Addition.** On some phones (for example, ZTE Blade HN) you need to start the main activity once, because phone don't let Broadcast Receiver to be activated if app is new and has never been opened. Even after updating app you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 <receiver android:name=".I2" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Another thing to notice

If your app installed on external storage(SD card), you will never receive Boot Complete action. So you have to specify the following in the manifest tag.

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. Nothing happened. I removed SD card and reinstalled app on phone memory also.

Comment: I would only disagree with the `never receive`. This works (well it works when I did the test) but there is a change that it doesn't if the intent is send before the card is mount.