# automatically starting my app using kotlin android broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an android application using kotlin, I want this app to automatically start when the phone is done booting, or whenever the user reboots the phone. I had made some research and realized it can be implemented using broadcast, however I have tried some codes but it's not working. Please  someone should help, I will be submitting the app in about 4days and this feature is keep me back.

**BootUpReceiver.kt**

```
package com.example.jofi

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent

class BootUpReceiver:BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
       

            if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent!!.action) {
                val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                context!!.startActivity(i)
            }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

lateinit var reciever:StartUpOnBootUpReciever
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//            val intent1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, RunServiceOnBoot::class.java)
//            startService(intent1)

            reciever = StartUpOnBootUpReciever()
reciever = StartUpOnBootUpReciever()
            IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED).also {
                registerReceiver(reciever, it)
            }
}

}
```

**ManiFest.xml**
I had included the following in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<receiver android:name=".StartUpOnBootUpReciever"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Your receiver class has a different name than the one you've used in the manifest. You don't need to do ``registerReceiver`` as well, and registering one in an ``Activity`` will only work as long as the activity is running (i.e. after a reboot it won't be registered). Also that ``BOOT_COMPLETED`` broadcast arrives a while after the device restarts (like it could be a minute or more)

Comment: So, please , do you suggest I remove the registerReceiver block?

Comment: Thanks I will try and make the changes. I will give a feed back immediately I try these changes

Comment: The ``registerReceiver`` bit shouldn't matter, it won't do anything anyway in this case, there's just no point keeping it there. Just use the manifest version, change ``name`` to ``.BootUpReceiver`` if that's what it's actually called. Throw a ``Log`` statement in ``onReceive`` to make sure it's actually working, and go from there

Comment: Boss, I am grateful, this is my first major job I wouldn't want to mess it up, thanks for responding, thanks for your time. I sincerely appreciate. I will   let you know of the outcome, when I eventually try it out

Comment: No worries! I can't promise you'll be able to do whatever you're trying to do, but this is how you handle BroadcastReceivers. You should probably read this whole page too: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Thanks alot, I will check through it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without any permission, it looks like a virus.

Comment: I managed to get the code as shown to me by someone but the intsructions are not responding, the app doesn't come up after boot/reboot @cactustictacs

Comment: Yeah like I said, I don't know if you'll actually be able to do what you're doing, and I don't have any experience with it. Like that link says at the end: *Do not start activities from broadcast receivers because the user experience is jarring; especially if there is more than one receiver* - that implies you *can* start one, but you *shouldn't*, and there may be restrictions on which broadcasts allow you to do that. Have a look at some other questions on the subject, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17611048/13598222 and see if they help you out

Comment: I will edit my code and get back to you, thanks for helping me out this much, I appreciate every little time you put in trying to help me  workout my  challenge